# How can I prevent my dog from barking so much?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there anyway - a mod or via console - to make the dog stop barking all the time?   Maybe it is not annoying to other people but I play a stealthy character.   I realize that the NPCs may not hear the dog bark but I find it annoying when I'm B&E in a home, sneaking past the sleeping occupants only to hear my dog bark like he's trying to tell someone Timmy is in the well.    When I sneak, my follower sneaks, at the least, the dog could be quiet. The same for the summoned companion that howls.

Again, I do realize that this is probably a problem for only a small group of people, but it resulted in me being unable to use the dog.   If I could even just turn the dog volume down, that would help.

I play with headphones and I play with a large stereo system.  To me the sound of a game (when I'm playing a stealthy character) is almost as important as the video.   Perhaps a mod could be made by the Skyrim Modder Gods in which other animals can be used and be used quietly.
Thanks

Comment: This is the entire reason I wont use dogs. I hate that barking while sneaking.

Comment: Kill it. That will solve your problem

Answer (score 11):

There are several, like [Quiet Dog](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=86) (total silence) and [Quieter Dogs](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/188) (lower volume). I haven't found any in the Steam Workshop thus far.

On a related note, I use zombies, which say "Uhh..." all the time. [Quiet Zombies](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/2097) removes that.

Comment: Unfortunately, the mod Quiet Dog no longer exists.

Comment: For the PS4, there is the mod [Quiet Dogs](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3029068).  For the XBox One, closest I could find is [Dogs Of Skyrim](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/4023470) which makes dogs quieter, but it's a complete overhaul of dogs.

Answer (score 2):

You should tell it to wait over there and then attack. The dog will come to help!

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: Yeah, wait over there and attack and get the dog to come help? What kind of answer is that there should of been down-votes.

Answer (score -1):

Get the mod “Dog Followers Are Huskies”. No constant barking!!!

XB1 link: https://bethesda.net/en/mods/SKYRIM/mod-detail/3328454

PC link: https://bethesda.net/en/mods/SKYRIM/mod-detail/3328442

PS4 link: https://bethesda.net/en/mods/SKYRIM/mod-detail/3328842