# Is there a way to limit the amount your followers talk in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

Simply put, some of the followers just talk too much, for example meeko (the dog) feels the need to bark every 5 seconds. Likewise the Spectral assasin has told me the same things over and over. I dont mind them talking every now and them but every few seconds gets on my nerve.

Are there any console commands that limits the speech of NPC's?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54784/how-can-i-prevent-my-dog-from-barking-so-much

Answer (score 2):

(These mods are more of a general solution that should reduce or minimize talking with most followers.)

I recommend using the mods **[No NPC Greetings](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/746)** and **[Move it Dammit for NPC Companions and Followers](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/4020)**.

*No NPC Greetings* will stop NPCs from auto-greeting you or reduce the distance required before an NPC automatically talks to you or greets you. *Move it Dammit* will increase the distance that Companions and Creatures walk to when being "bumped", making them keep their distance from you at most times and lessening the chances of them talking to you (*I wish these were real life mods*).

For removal of even more annoying dialogue, also install the [Shut The F--- Up](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/10023) mod.

I don't know of a mod that specifically reduces the Spectral Assassin's talking. About the dog, [there are several solutions in this related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54784/4797).

Answer (score 0):

The mod [Silent Followers](http://www.skyrimnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=5658) does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Except it only works for 1 follower. Maybe check the description next time?

Answer (score -2):

The mod [Amazing Follower Tweaks](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/15524/?) allows you to make your followers limit their banter.

Comment: Could you provide more information? Does it say that in the mod description?

Comment: The mod actually adds a "No idle chatter" option in the AFT options dialog page, but it didn't work for me (maybe because I also have "Follower Commentary Overhaul" installed).